# Como añadir titulos verticales a un QTableWidget

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt

Estoy utilizando `QTableWiget` para listar unos datos en forma de tabal el problema es que al momento de querer añadir un titulo en el `verticalheader` no se muestra.

He estado buscando al respecto pero no encontre informacion que me ayudara.

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTableWidget,QHeaderView,QAction
from PyQt5 import QtCore
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.header = QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.header.addAction(QAction("ahaol"))


        self.tabla = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tabla.resize(400,400)
        self.tabla.setVerticalHeader(self.header)

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el metodo `setVerticalHeader` esta mal implementado, hay que reemplazarlo por `setVerticalHeaderLabels()`, y directamente este metodo no recibe un string si no que recibe una lista de strings es decir un elemento iterable.

Por lo tanto el codigo quedaria de la siguiente manera:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QTableWidget,QHeaderView,QAction
from PyQt5 import QtCore
class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

       # self.header = QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Vertical) <--- (-)
       #    self.header.addAction(QAction("ahaol")) <--- (-)

        self.Lista = ['uno','dos'] # <--- (+)


        self.tabla = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tabla.resize(400,400)
        self.tabla.setColumnCount(3) # <--- (+)
        self.tabla.setRowCount(2) # <--- (+)
       # self.tabla.setVerticalHeader(self.header) <--- (-)
        self.tabla.setVerticalHeaderLabels(self.Lista)

app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
m.resize(800,600)
app.exec_()
```